# GroupBy a list of associations with their keys

Tags: associations, gathering

How can I go from

```
as =  {
    <|A->{1,11},B->{1,12},C->{1,13}|>,
    <|A->{2,21},B->{2,22},C->{2,23}|>,
    <|A->{3,31},B->{3,32},C->{3,33}|>
}
```

to

```
<|
     "A" -> {{1, 11}, {2, 21}, {3, 31}}, 
     "B" -> {{1, 12}, {2, 22}, {3, 32}}, 
     "C" -> {{1, 13}, {2, 23}, {3, 33}}
|>
```

I think I should use some variation of `GroupBy[as,condition]` but I can't really figure out what condition should be.

Comment: No need for the version-10 tag; that is implied by the use of `Association`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This operation is performed by [`Merge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Merge.html):

```
Merge[as, Identity]
```

> ```
> <|A -> {{1, 11}, {2, 21}, {3, 31}},
>   B -> {{1, 12}, {2, 22}, {3, 32}}, 
>   C -> {{1, 13}, {2, 23}, {3, 33}}|>
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Another approach:

```
AssociationThread[Keys[as][[1]], Transpose@Values[as]]
```

> ```
> <|A -> {{1, 11}, {2, 21}, {3, 31}},
>   B -> {{1, 12}, {2, 22}, {3, 32}}, 
>   C -> {{1, 13}, {2, 23}, {3, 33}}|>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
GroupBy[Catenate @ Normal @ as, First -> Last]
```

[image]