# Association Sum by key

Tags: expression-manipulation, rule

I get results from [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) as a list of associations.

```
{{a -> 1, b -> 2}, {a -> 3, b -> 4}}
```

I would like to sum values by key.

For the example, I would like to get something like `{a -> 4, b -> 6}`.

Comment: `Merge[{{a -> 1, b -> 2}, {a -> 3, b -> 4}}, Total]`?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Adding Rule Solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129534/5478)

Comment: See also [(4332)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121) and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a -> 1, b -> 2}, {a -> 3, b -> 4}};
Normal@GroupBy[Flatten@list, Keys -> Values, Total];
(* {a -> 4, b -> 6} *)

Thread[Union @@ Keys[#] -> Apply[Plus, Values[#], {1}]]&@ Transpose[list]
(* {a -> 4, b -> 6} *)
```

as suggested by @J.M.

```
Normal@Merge[{{a -> 1, b -> 2}, {a -> 3, b -> 4}}, Total] (* applying Normal if you
want the answer with Head list *)
```