# Is there a way to divide associations by key?

Tags: equation-solving, associations

I have the following two associations

```
<|A->2.02015,B->1.98025|> <|B->0.538000,A->0.462000|>
```

I would like to produce a third association where

```
new = <|A->  2.02015/0.462000, B->1.98025/0.538000|>
```

I found the following answer which is close, except it uses Total. Is there an equivalent for quotients (Quotient does not work)? Or is there a better way to do it?

[Association Sum by key](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146629/association-sum-by-key)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = <|A -> 2.02015, B -> 1.98025|>;
b = <|B -> 0.538000, A -> 0.462000|>;
Merge[{a, b}, Apply[Divide]]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to use builtin commands like `Merge` you could always roll your own function to do it.

```
a = <|A -> 2.02015, B -> 1.98025|>
b = <|B -> 0.538000, A -> 0.462000|>
keys = Keys[a];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now simply build your new association using pure function like this

```
<| # -> (a[#]/b[#]) & /@ keys|>
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
new = <|A->  2.02015/0.462000, B->1.98025/0.538000|>
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = <|A -> 2.02015, B -> 1.98025|>;
b = <|B -> 0.538000, A -> 0.462000|>;
```

In the above case it's simply

```
a / KeySort[b]
```

[image]

If we don't know the sort status:

```
KeySort[a] / KeySort[b]
```

[image]

Or, alternatively,

```
Divide @@ Map[KeySort, {a, b}]
```

[image]